# Как скопировать элементы массива в заданные позиции другого массива?

Tags: java, массивы

Есть 2 массива, наполненные данными. Возьмем конкретный пример без абстракции. В одном массиве 2 элемента, в другом - 4. Элементы не повторяются.

```
int[] a = new int[] { a1, a2, };
int[] b = new int[] { b3, b4, b5, b6, };
int[] c = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };
```

Необходимо наполнить 3 массив этими данными. Не важно, создавать ли новый массив длиной 6 или использовать этот. Задача состоит в том, чтобы задать элементы массива `а` определенным индексам массива `с`.

Например, положить их в с[1] и с[3]:

```
int[] c = new int[] {0, a1, 0, a2, 0, 0, };
```

И аналогичную операцию сделать с массивом `b`. Т.е. положить его элементы в заранее определенные мной позиции другого массива:

```
int[] c = new int[] { b3, a1, b4, a2, b5, b6, };
```

Сложность не так важна, элементов не много. Интересует хотя бы приблизительный алгоритм, или правильный подход к решению.

Comment: Эмм... `int[] c = new int[6]; c[1] = a[0]; c[3] = a[1]`?

Comment: @Regent Похоже что да :)

Comment: @ВАНЕЧКА можно сделать двумерный массив - номер исходного массива, номер элемента - {{0,0},{1,0},{0,1}... и собирать в соответствии с ним